# Can't load PYQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I get this error; any comments

Couldn't load PyQGIS.
Python support will be disabled.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/core.so: undefined symbol: _ZN28QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem19createFromUserInputE7QString

Python version:
2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 23:06:40) 
[GCC 4.6.3]

QGIS version:
1.8.0-Lisboa 'Lisboa', exported

Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/norm/.qgis//python', '/home/norm/.qgis//python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']

Answer (score 4):

```
$ c++filt _ZN28QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem19createFromUserInputE7QString
QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem::createFromUserInput(QString)
```

[QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem::createFromUserInput(QString)](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#ac1fcbf32930a7c7a6d012633f4964e74) is new in 1.8.  Are you sure your `core.so` is linked to the current library? Check with `ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/core.so | grep qgis_core`.

Maybe you still have an old version of the libraries installed (possibly from the former 1.8 branch).

Comment: libqgis_core.so.1.8.0 => /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.1.8.0 (0xb6d94000)

Comment: Ok, so where did that library come from? Did you build yourself or installed a package?  Did you install/build the python extension from the same source?

Comment: I just installed from the QGIS page following instructions What commands would you suggest to completely delete all qgis from my drive and then I could start over

Comment: To see which packages are installed you could run:
`dpkg -l | grep qgis`

BTW which distribution are you using?

To remove all QGIS packages run:
`apt-get remove --purge ".*qgis.*"`

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help Jef. This is what I got back; have a 1.9 reference which is probably source of problems